# Jquery Fade Cycle through paragraphs and display one item at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I cannot get it to just display one at a time. It has to do a full cycle before it displays just one paragraph. Pulling my hair out.

```
$(function(){

    setInterval(function(){$('.forumFeed > :first-child').fadeOut(3000).next('p').delay(3000).fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('.forumFeed');}, 5000);
});
```

https://codepen.io/capseaslug/pen/yqyBXB

Comment: When you are creating the elements, check to see if the child is not the first child.  If it is not, set the style on the child to be display none, so that only the first one is showing at the start.

Comment: I actually tried this, using css. And it still had to cycle through everything for it to work so results not as expected. Notice how it flashes through them all then starts the fad animation loop: https://codepen.io/capseaslug/pen/NBPezw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide all but the first paragraph tag by default.  Inside the setInterval hide the one that is showing and display the next one (controlled by an index variable).

To make the items fade in/out nicely you can fade in the next element after the visible one is finished hiding.

Added some variables at the top to play with the aesthetics / number of items looped through.

SO didn't have moment.js so I hard coded some string.  [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WKbYKw) for a working version.

```js
var numberOfItems = 10;
var flipSpeed = 2000;
var fadeOutSpeed = 500;
var fadeInSpeed = 200;

(function(c){
 var uniquename = 'rssfeed' // id of target div
 var query = 'select * from rss(0,' + numberOfItems + ') where url = "https://forums.mankindreborn.com/f/-/index.rss"'; // RSS Target, 0,5 signifies number of entries to show
  
 var numretries = 1; // increase this number (number of retries) if you're still having problems

  //////// No Need To Edit Beyond Here Unless You Want To /////////

 var counter = typeof c === 'number'? c : numretries;
 var thisf = arguments.callee;
 var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
 var s = document.createElement('script');
 window["callback_" + uniquename + (--counter)] = function(r){
  head.removeChild(s);
  if(r && r.query && r.query.count === 0 && counter > 0){
   return thisf(counter);
  }
  //r now contains the result of the YQL Query as a JSON
   
  var feedmarkup = '';
  var feed = r.query.results.item // get feed as array of entries
    
  for (var i=0; i<feed.length; i++) {    
      feedmarkup += '<p><span class="firstrowwrap"><a href="' + feed[i].link + '">';
   feedmarkup += feed[i].title + '</a> <span class="comments"> Replies: ';
      feedmarkup += feed[i].comments + ' </span></span><span class="secondRow"> <i class="fas fa-feather-alt"></i> ' ;
      feedmarkup += feed[i].creator + ' <span class="posttime"> Last Post: ';
      //pubishdate since
      publishDate = feed[i].pubDate; 
      var inDate = publishDate;
      var publisheddate = new Date(inDate);      
      feedmarkup += 'moment.js is missing ' + '</span></span></p>';
      //endpublishdate since
  }
  document.getElementById(uniquename).innerHTML = feedmarkup;
 };
 var baseurl = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=";
 s.src = baseurl + encodeURIComponent(query) + "&format=json&callback=callback_" + uniquename + counter;
 head.append(s);
})();

$(function(){   
  var index = 0;  
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#rssfeed>p:visible').fadeOut(fadeOutSpeed, ()=> {
      $('#rssfeed>p').eq(index).fadeIn(fadeInSpeed);  
    });    
    
    index++;
    if(index === $('#rssfeed>p').length){
      index = 0;
    }    
  }, flipSpeed);
});
```

```css
#main-container {
  padding:4em;
  background: #333;
  font-family: 'exo'
}

#rssfeed p:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}

a{
  font-weight:
    500;
  color: #68ddda;
}
a:hover{
  color: #4ca7a4;
}

.firstrowwrap{
  display: flex; 
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.secondRow{
  display: block;
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}


#rssfeed p{
  background-color: #212121;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  color: #464646;
  
}

.comments{
 height: 18px;
 position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-left: 8px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.comments:after{
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 background-color: #969696;
 border-radius: 2px;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-left: 4px;
  
}

.posttime{
 float: right; 
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid" id="main-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="forumFeed" id="rssfeed"></div>     
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much was not expecting to get **THIS** much help haha!

Comment: Hah yeah I might have gone a little overboard, I thought the pen was neat though :)

Comment: Thank you for helping it come to fruition :)